# Division of polynomials in logarithm

Tags: logarithms

I was solving some problems and got to this logarithmic equation:

$$\log_2(\frac{36x^2-24x+4}{3x^2+8x+5})=0$$

How to solve this equation?

Comment: How have you tried to solve the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\log_{2}(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}$$ then
\begin{align}
\log_2(\frac{36x^2-24x+4}{3x^2+8x+5}) &= 0 \\
\ln(\frac{36x^2-24x+4}{3x^2+8x+5}) &= 0 \\
\frac{36x^2-24x+4}{3x^2+8x+5} &= 1 \\
36 x^2 - 24 x + 4 &= 3 x^2 + 8 x + 5 \\
33 x^2 - 32 x -1 &= 0 \\
x^2 - 2\left(\frac{16}{33}\right) x - \frac{1}{33} &= 0 \\
x &= \frac{16}{33} \pm \sqrt{\frac{4 \cdot 16^2}{33^2} + \frac{4}{33}} \\
&= \frac{2}{33} \, (8 \pm \sqrt{16^2 + 33}) \\
&= \frac{2}{33} \, (8 \pm 17) \\
&= \left\{ \frac{50}{33}, - \frac{18}{33} \right\}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It must be $$\frac{36x^2-24x+4}{3x^2+8x+15}=1$$
Solve the equation
$$33x^2-32x-11=0$$
One solution is given by $$x=\frac{1}{33} \left(16-\sqrt{619}\right)$$

Comment: Aha thanks for the information. What kind of method would be best to use in the division?

Comment: I would multiply by the denominator and solve a quadratic equation.